# How to read base class properties from my interface instance

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, c#-4.0, reflection

```
 public interface IMyService
{
    void GetValue();
}

public class MyService : ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
{
    public MyService()
    {
        EndPoint = "Test";
    }
    public void GetValue()
    {

    }
}
public interface ICommunication
{
    void Start();
}

public class ClientBase<T> : ICommunication
{
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public void Start()
    {
    }
}
```

**My Test Project**

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        ICommunication communication = new MyService();
    }
}
```

**How do i access the EndPoint properties from communication object?**

My Goal is to read the value of the EndPoint from the ICommunication instance. how do i convert the ICommunication interface to ClientBase Generic class

Note:we have multiple service classes.Is there a way to get the instance of ClientBase from my ICommunication

Answer (score 0):

The interface `ICommunication` does not have `EndPoint` and when you write this line of code:

```
ICommunication communication = new MyService();
```

`communication` is a reference of type `ICommunication` but it is pointing to an instance of `MyService`. Thus you can do this to cast it to `MyService` and then access it:

```
string ep = (communication as MyService).EndPoint;
```

Comment: I forget to put this one. we have multiple service classes.Is there a way to get the instance of ClientBase<T> from my ICommunication